# Socket Time Out Exception on Async Java Http Service calls using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor

I am new in using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and `CompletableFuture` for Async Operations. Since the service I am developing should have good speed and performance should not be impacted so I had to leverage the use of Async calls. However, I am not sure what's wrong in the code, the service performs fine on individual requests but once load occurs on the service or load test is performed, the service stops responding, it gets stuck in sending request from postman after the load and it shows "Socket Timeout Exception: Read Time out" in Soap UI Load test results.
Below is the service level operation:

```
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<FindWorkOrdersResponse> findWorkOrders(BusinessUnit businessUnit,
            FindWorkOrdersRequest findWorkOrdersRequest) {

        CompletableFuture<FindWorkOrdersResponse> result = null;
        try {
            result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                return ibsAdapter.findWorkOrders(businessUnit, findWorkOrdersRequest);
            }, taskExecutor).thenApplyAsync(findWorkOrdersResp -> {
                if (findWorkOrdersResp.getWorkOrders() != null && !findWorkOrdersResp.getWorkOrders().isEmpty()) {
                    findWorkOrdersResp.getWorkOrders().parallelStream().forEach(wo -> {
                        wo.setInstallerInfo(mustangAdapter.getCustomer(businessUnit, wo.getServiceProviderId()));
                    });
                }
                return findWorkOrdersResp;
            }, taskExecutor);
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            logger.warn(
                    "FindWorkOrders was rejected for async execution, falling back to non-critical execution mode: {}",
                    e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The data returned from first service call is a list of size 50 and for each index second service call is being made.
The task executor settings are below:

```
 @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.setCorePoolSize(MdcConstants.CORE_POOL_SIZE); 
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(MdcConstants.MAX_POOL_SIZE);    
        executor.setQueueCapacity(MdcConstants.QUEUE_CAPACITY); 
        //executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl());
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(2);

        executor.setTaskDecorator(runnable -> {
            Map<String, String> mdcContext = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
            return () -> {
                try {
                    if (mdcContext != null) {
                        MDC.setContextMap(mdcContext);
                    }
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    MDC.clear();
                }
            };
        });
        return executor;
    }
```

The core pool size and max pool size are set to below values:

```
public static final Integer CORE_POOL_SIZE=2;
public static final Integer MAX_POOL_SIZE=100;
public static final Integer QUEUE_CAPACITY=0;
```

Socket time out of ibs adapter service call is set to 600000. Increasing this also doesn't fix the issue. The second service call is very small and returns data in milliseconds and that is probably not causing the issue. Anyone please let help me fix this. I thought increasing core pool size, max pool size or socket timeout will fix it but it didn't. Socket timeout exception read timeout should not occur on increasing socket timeout but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Why should it help? You are using a `parallelStream` which doesn't use this `TaskExecutor` . Adding more threads might not even make your system faster it could even make it slower, depending on how many cores you have, memory size etc. Also the socket timeout is the response of **your** service call not the calls you are making in your API.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I'll remove `parallelStream` and perform load test again.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Removing `parallelStream` and using `stream` instead also didn't fix it. Load test again failed on 50 threads iteration with Socket timeout. So it wasn't causing it

Comment: And again, the socket timeout is on the client side (all the requests take too much time to get a response to the client) the timeout isn't on the calls to the services.

Comment: someone please help me out here. I have tried every possible thing that came in my mind and now I am running out of ideas @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: @M.Deinum the requests work fine on 10 threads iteration and they start failing on 50 iteration load test with socket timeout. If the requests are taking too much time to get a response, what possible issue could be in my code that I can fix this issue with so that the api works under load as well

Comment: Ofcourse they are... As there are no more cores to fulfil the request, they wait, until a core is free. This waiting takes too long resulting in a timeout on the client NOT the requests you are sending. Instead of using multi threading, I strongly suggest writing this for a single thread and you might even get a bit more performance then a single one (just only use the `parallelStream()` let everything else be normal (so no `TaskExecutor` and `CompletableFuture`). And remove the `@Async` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum during development of this api, it was single thread in the beginning but it didn't give the speed results as they were with async. Infact service was taking too long and I was asked to improve the performance of api. I then used async. The service brings the first page and is very critical, we can't afford having speed decrease in seconds. Also, for testing I removed async and used fixed thread pool of 10 threads, it also failed on 50 iterations load test

Comment: Please read my comments. Make it single threaded AND for each request to the backend use a parallelStream. What you currently did doesn't improve anything, also using @ASync adds another thread. You are basically swamping your cores with threads and it doesn't have time to complete anything in reasonable time. As mentioned multi-threading can even make it slower.

Comment: Can i share my code snippet with you somewhere? Just to be sure I am doing exactly what you are saying.@M.Deinum

Comment: Your question is the place to share code (or create a sample repository and link that). Also those repository calls you are making are those HTTP requests or are those just queries? If it is the latter you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum they are http java web service requests. Also I have removed `Async`, `TaskExecutor` and `CompletableFuture` . First service brings the arraylist data and then based on this data I am using parallel stream to fetch details against each index via another http service. Still it gives me Socket Timeout Exception on backend against the first service call.

Comment: It isn't giving a a timeout in the backend, it gives a timeout in Postman because **your** service isn't responding. Those are different things. Things are already async (each request incoming, has its own thread). Without seeing everything that is being done (sending the requests etc.) it is simply impossible to answer this and you probably need more consulting than one can give here in stackoverflow. (Or at least that is what I expect).

Comment: `public FindWorkOrdersResponse findWorkOrders(BusinessUnit businessUnit,
   FindWorkOrdersRequest findWorkOrdersRequest) {

  FindWorkOrdersResponse result = ibsAdapter.findWorkOrders(businessUnit, findWorkOrdersRequest);

  if (result.getWorkOrders() != null && !result.getWorkOrders().isEmpty()) {
   result.getWorkOrders().parallelStream().forEach(wo -> {
    wo.setInstallerInfo(mustangAdapter.getCustomer(businessUnit, wo.getServiceProviderId()));
   });
  }
  return result;
 }` is this what you were saying? @M.Deinum